# Breeze auth middleware redirect back login page itself

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, breeze

When I request to login on breeze, user date is passing but auth middleware redirect back to login page. It has also 302 response in result.
Do you have any experience on it ?
I use Laravel 8
Breeze Package

Comment: Same here, nothing seems to help. :-/

Comment: I could not find a solution but I have installed a new Breeze Project and moved controllers to new one. Do not spend your time to solve that problem, My suggestion to install new breeze app and move your projec to the in. I really tried to find a solution but ı could not. Now, it works on new project.

Answer (score 0):

After installation **Breeze**, I had to make changes and it's down.
The solution for my case is to **install again** the **package**.